# How a child element can hide a portion of its parent's border

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I have a tab control that features unstable behavior. I'm attempting to hide that portion of the bottom border that represents the top of my "folder" where it lies directly beneath the active tab, mimicking a real file folder. Desired look:

[image]

But both Chrome and Edge have a tendency to sometimes not fully hide the horizontal line. If I change the browser to a different Zoom level, a 1-pixel line appears:

[image]

This also happens at times when dragging the box around, then disappears when I let go. Or it'll be fine in some components, but the same code acts up in others. I can't seem to get rid of this line consistently, so I'm wondering if there is **a more reliable way to hide that line under the active tab**?

I think my main issue is I cannot seem to make anything from a `.tab` overlay the detail area below. It's like `z-index` refuses to place the tabs on top.

Here's my current code.

```css
  * {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    --color-dramatic-light-h: 0;
    --color-dramatic-light-s: 0%;
    --color-dramatic-light-l: 93%;
    --color-dramatic-light-fg: hsl(192,46%,42%);
    --color-dramatic-light: hsl(var(--color-dramatic-light-h), var(--color-dramatic-light-s), var(--color-dramatic-light-l));
    --color-accent: hsl(var(--color-accent-h), var(--color-accent-s), var(--color-accent-l));
    font-size: 12px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: color-accent;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .svlt-grid-item {
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 100;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2.5em 1em black;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    touch-action: none;
    position: absolute;
    will-change: auto;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    width: 1362.796875px;
    height: 880px;
    transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s;
    transform: translate(701.3984375px, 166px);
  }

  .popupOverlayWrapper {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
  }

  .header {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.1em;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .tabs {
    --tab-border-color: hsl(var(--color-dramatic-light-h),var(--color-dramatic-light-s),calc(var(--color-dramatic-light-l) * 0.2 ));
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    height: 2.5em;
    width: 100%;
    isolation: isolate;
  }

  .tabs:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--tab-border-color);
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .tab {
    --color-tab-gradient: hsl(var(--color-dramatic-light-h),var(--color-dramatic-light-s),calc(var(--color-dramatic-light-l) * 0.85 ));
    position: relative;
    padding: 0.1em 0.6em;
    margin: 0 -0.1em;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px white;
    border-radius: 0.6em 0.6em 0 0;
    border: 1px solid var(--tab-border-color);
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, white, var(--color-tab-gradient));
    box-shadow: 0 0.3em 0.3em var(--tab-border-color);
    color: var(--color-dramatic-light-fg);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Fredoka One', 'Arial Black', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 1em;
    z-index: 0;
  }

  .tab:before,
  .tab:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    bottom: -1px;
    width: 0.60em;
    height: 0.60em;
    border: 1px solid var(--tab-border-color);
  }

  .tab:before {
    left: -0.60em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.60em;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
    box-shadow: 0.2em 0.2em 0 var(--color-tab-gradient);
  }

  .tab:after {
    right: -0.60em;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0.60em;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
    box-shadow: -0.2em 0.2em 0 var(--color-tab-gradient);
  }

  .tab.activeTab {
    z-index: 2;
    border-bottom-color: white;
    background: none white;
  }

  .tab.activeTab:before {
    box-shadow: 0.2em 0.2em 0 white;
  }

  .tab.activeTab:after {
    box-shadow: -0.2em 0.2em 0 white;
  }
```

```html
<div draggable="false" class="svlt-grid-item" style="width: 1362.796875px; height:880px; transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s; transform: translate(701.3984375px, 166px); ">
  <div class="popupOverlayWrapper">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="tabs">
        <button class="tab activeTab">
          Listener Detail
        </button>
        <button class="tab">
          Listener Services
        </button>
        <button class="tab">
          Instances Served
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used your code and made a little modification to adjust the position of some elements by `margin-bottom`, and revome the `box-shadow` of these tab, I'm not sure if this will meet your needs:

```
.tabs:before {
                position: absolute;
                content: "";
                width: 100%;
                bottom: 0px;
                left: 0;
                border-bottom: 1px solid var(--tab-border-color);
                margin-bottom: 0.5px;
                z-index: 1;
            }

        .tab {
            --color-tab-gradient: hsl(var(--color-dramatic-light-h),var(--color-dramatic-light-s),calc(var(--color-dramatic-light-l) * 0.85 ));
            position: relative;
            padding: 0.1em 0.6em;
            margin: 0 -0.1em;
            height: 100%;
            cursor: pointer;
            outline-color: aliceblue;
            text-align: center;
            text-shadow: 0 1px 2px white;
            border-radius: 0.6em 0.6em 0 0;
            border: 1px solid var(--tab-border-color);
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, var(--color-tab-gradient));
            /*box-shadow: 0 0.3em 0.3em var(--tab-border-color);*/
            color: var(--color-dramatic-light-fg);
            text-decoration: none;
            font-family: 'Fredoka One', 'Arial Black', sans-serif;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            line-height: 1em;
            
            z-index: 0;
        }
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: That certainly does remove the ghost line under the active tab. However, it does so by moving the entire visible line up, so that the line under Listener Services and Instances Served is now thicker and doesn't look right. Can you do this without thickening or moving that line? Specifically, is there a change I can make to `.tab.activeTab` to cover the line? I can create a ::before pseudo element that boxes the line but it refuses to overlay it, no matter what my z-index is.

Comment: I tried a lot of modifications, but I'm afraid I can't achieve such a requirement, as I mentioned, this problem only occurs at certain zoom sizes. So I think it's a browser rendering issue.